# Manually change or catch the message for invalid CSRF token in Symfony2.1

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, csrf-protection

I'm using **Symfony2.1**.
It has a builtin **CSRF protection** for the forms. The error message returned when the CSRF token is invalid is: "*The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form*".

I show it on the top of the form in my Twig template by using the classic call:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

How can I change the returned message?

In alternative, a more advanced possibility is to catch this error type in order to show a lot of options/links in my Twig template.
Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to set in the file `validators.{locale_code}.yml` to set a translation for key `The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form`?
To change the default message you can try this out:

```
 #MyBundle\Resources\translations\validators.en.yml

 The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form : My custom CSRF error
```

The error message is thrown [here](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Csrf/EventListener/CsrfValidationListener.php) and it is of FormError class...thus it should be possible to translate it.

Comment: No I didn't! Where can I find/set that file? Moreover, is there any way to override the default `CsrfValidationListener` class?

Comment: I didn't try it out yet, but for sure you could set a listener on the form builder (just check the repo linked above on how to that) and attach the listener event with a higher priority of the default one addedd by the CSRF protection.

Comment: Do the listeners have a priority?

Comment: [yes](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilderInterface.html#method_addEventListener)