# Symfony2 form error handling, custom message for CSFR

Tags: symfony

Is there any way to customize error message for [CSFR protection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection) in a Symfony2 form?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452903/manually-change-or-catch-the-message-for-invalid-csrf-token-in-symfony2-1